# start apache script

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I've got Apache installed on my local Linux (sabayon) OS, just for programming testing.

What I want is a script so that the server starts right away when I want it.

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# een script dat de apache server start
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

The only problem is that Apache needs root privileges, but I'm a normal user. Now can I run this script from the command line with `sudo ./apache_start.sh`, but I don't want that. I just want to double click on it and start the Apache server.

So what can I do so the script is run as root instead of the normal user?

I don't care if there is a prompt that asks for the password, I just don't want to open a console, navigate to the file and so on.

Comment: Have you tried adding `sudo` to the beginning of the line where you're starting Apache?

Comment: yes, when i start the script trough cli, it ask for password, but when i double click, it doesn't do it. And when i check the states of apache, it didnt start

Comment: How about this- go into a console session and then type `sudo visudo`. This will open up a `sudoers` file which you will have the right to edit. Scroll down to near the bottom, and you should see your username with something formatted like `username ALL=(ALL)`. Append `PASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2` to the end of that line, then save the file. Then try doing your script again (with sudo prepended)

Comment: didn't work either

Comment: Hm. Have you tried launching the script from the console to see if it works?

Comment: yes, it works when i enter the password (for sudo) but i wnat to skip the password section...

Comment: Why not just leave it running?

Comment: i want to run it only if i'm going to develop a website. and i hoped there whas a easy whay to achief it instead of opening an terminal.....

Comment: Wouldn't that be started by system ? Why doing it alone

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the default init script if you want to do what you are doing. Also, you cannot start it without root privileges if you want it to run on port 80, since only root can start listeners on port 80.

You have two options as I see it. Run on a higher port than 1024 and then execute apache from the command line manually. Or use sudo:

```
visudo
```

Add a line with your username

```
username ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2 start, /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

And your desktop shortcut thing tell it to execute

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Comment: i've got the following line added in visudo:   marc ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apach2 start, /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
 and the script is excutable, and with sudo in front, but still asking for password

Comment: edit, add an e to the word apache, but still not working

Comment: Use `sudo -l` to confirm you see the command you're trying to configure after using `visudo`.  `sudo -l` will tell you what commands you can run using `sudo`.

Comment: this is the output i get from that command:    User marc may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/apache2 start, (root) /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
    (root) ALL

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gksudo` to acquire root privileges visually, which is nice.

**apache-start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$EUID" = "0" ]; then
    # we're root, so just run it
    service apache2 start
    exit 0
fi

# otherwise, try running it with a visual prompt for superuser
gksudo service apache2 start
```